# Form not resetting after this.setState - React

Tags: reactjs

Trying to reset a search input field but setState is not working properly

I've tried a couple of the stack overflow responses but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something really small. Just not sure what

I have a state: searchInput that lives in App.js, which I pass into the search field into a Search Input component as follow:

SearchInputComponent.js

```
// the Search and SearchInput are styled components so basically div and an input
  <Search>
    <SearchInput
      type="text"
      onChange={this.props.updateSearch}
      name="searchInput"
      value={this.props.searchInput}
      placeholder="Search for a food..."
    />
    <SearchButton onClick={this.props.getFoodData}>Search</SearchButton>
  </Search>
```

I know the searchInput is passing because I'm able to see the typed item in the field.

I have a function called getFoodData which searches an api regarding the searchInput and I'm able to get the results

App.js - searchInput state lives here and is changed when typing on the input field by

```
updateSearch = e => {
 this.setState({
   [e.target.name]: e.target.value
 });
};

//Code to check the API:  

getFoodData = food => {
food = this.state.searchInput;
let encodedFood = food.replace(" ", "%20");
this.setState({ showModal: true});
axios
  .get(
    `https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/parser?ingr=${encodedFood}&app_id=${EDAMAM_API_ID}&app_key=${EDAMAM_API_KEY}`
  )
  .then(response => {
    console.log('pre-reset', this.state.searchInput);
    this.setState({
      searchResults: response.data.hints,
      searchInput: "",
      noResultError: "",
      resultsLoading: false
    });
    console.log("search results", this.state.searchResults);
    console.log("search input", this.state.searchInput);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.setState({
      searchInput: "",
      noResultError: "No results found",
      showModal: true,
      searchResults: []
    });
    console.log("error", error);
  });
```

};

These functions are then passed into SearchInputComponent as such in the JSX

```
        <SearchInputComponent
        updateSearch={this.props.updateSearch}
        searchInput={this.props.searchInput}
        getFoodData={this.props.getFoodData}
      />
```

am I missing something on why this isn't clearing the search field, even if my searchInput is reset after the response? I can see it in console before the reset and after the reset and searchInput is clearing.

I expected the search field to clear out with the original placeholder to show or even an empty field.

Comment: how are your `<Search>` and the api calling code arranged wrt each other?

Comment: I edited the question to show the file structure a bit better. the functions live in App.just to have a main parent component. While the SearchInputComponent is a child component that's getting the function and state from App.js as props. 

There's a couple of layers App --> Header --> NavBar --> SearchInput, but each prop is being passed from layer to layer. 

I know could use Redux because of the prop drilling nightmare, but not an option at the moment since this project is done only in React. Just wanted to see if I missed something.

Comment: When passing the functions in a component, not sure why you used {this.props.<functionName>}. If you are passing a function to another component, then no need to use "props". try removing props from {this.props.updateSearch} and other 2 arguments.
If this doesn't work, could you please provide more error logs that the component is throwing?

Comment: @dp_chua can you provide a sandbox example with minimum code?

Comment: Actually figured out the error, it was a simple typo when passing props.i had a 3rd component that I had to go through to in order to pass it to the specific component and that had an error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you should use `componentWillReceiveProps` in `SearchInputComponent` to update the `SearchInputComponent` state when the props change. In `SearchInputComponent`, when initially setting your state, set the state value to the prop value, `this.state = { searchInput: this.props.searchInput }` and use `this.state.searchInput` for the field value.